# Facebook Conceal takes up a lot of space on an app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-conceal

I recently read an blog post on how the NYTimes managed to optimised their android app:

http://www.nytimes.com/glogin?URI=http%3A%2F%2Fopen.blogs.nytimes.com%2F2016%2F02%2F11%2Fimproving-startup-time-in-the-nytimes-android-app%2F%3F_r%3D1

I uploaded my app to the nimbledroid and found out that Facebook Conceal takes up about 2.6mb of an app that is only 11.7mb in size.

This is the results from Nimbledroid - all those libconceal are from Facebook Conceal library:

[image]

I imported conceal into my app by doing the following:

```
compile 'com.facebook.conceal:conceal:1.0.3@aar'
```

Is it necessary to have all those .so files within the app for Conceal to function properly?

The smaller the android app size, the better.

Comment: Those 5 files are for 5 different platforms. You never need all. I don't know if you did something wrong or Google automatically just ships the right one.

Comment: I think because there are so many different platforms android can be used on, if u use that one import, it includes all 5 files so that whatever platform u use, your app will still work. On the Facebook conceal website, it says conceal is a small and fast library to use. Its definitely not a small library.

Comment: But when someone downloads the app they will just download it to one platform. Google or you should be able to just ship one of the files

Comment: Well my app is not on the app store yet - I'm just testing my apk and directly uploading it to nimbledroid. The apk includes everything. I don't imagine google will strip out the .so files from my signed apk file when i uploaded it to the play store so i guess conceal wholesales all the .so files for all platforms together.On the conceal website, it says " Conceal ships with only a select number of encryption algorithms from OpenSSL which make it much smaller (85KB)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coders at Facebook Conceal managed to reduced the size of Conceal to one tenth the size of the original library that was included with my app:

Download their lastest library:

> com.facebook.conceal:conceal:1.1.3@aar

[image]